# Overwrite Bootstrap carousel Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Overwrite Bootstrap carousel Javascript To Active Three item. 
I Have trouble with other people solution on carousel showing multiple item, the solution is copy image to one active item. The effect is not what i want, which it slides off the entire copy slide and switch to next active number with copy slide.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 4000
      })

      $('.carousel .item').each(function(){
        var next = $(this).next();
        if (!next.length) {
          next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        for (var i=0;i<1;i++) {
          next=next.next();
          if (!next.length) {
              next = $(this).siblings(':first');
              }

          next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
      });
```

What do i change exactly to NOT slide off the entire slide, but just one picture at once. both forward and backwards

Answer (score 1):

Check this: 
codepen.io/mephysto/pen/ZYVKRY
to see what you can do here.

However, default bootstrap carousel is not the best anyway. I'd strongly recommend switching to Owl Carousel: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/ it has better support for mobile devices.

Comment: That is very helpful, kinda stuck on this bootstrap version. but i'm still experiencing the three slide goes entire off and whole new 3 slides comes in effect on your link. but i like the fresh start and easy function to make my job better.

Comment: But i'm still going wait and see if anyone can actually help me solve my current situation, it just will help me in growing and understanding more